# Uncaught (in promise) even tho try catch it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function for adding item

```
const handleOnAdd = ({ values }) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!exists(values["subject-name"])) {
            reject("no name");
        } else if (
            !validNumber(values["credit"]) ||
            !validNumber(values["periods"])
        ) {
            reject("not type of number");
        } else {
            newSubject(values);
            setIsLoading(true);
            resolve();
        }
    });
};
```

then an element handle to add item

```
<ItemToAdd
    // ...
    onClick={(event) => {
        handleOnAdd({
            values,
            shouldRemoveChild: true,
            event,
        })
            .then((res) => {
                console.error(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                defaultFailCB(err);
            });
    }}
/>
```

but my try/catch does not catch the reject value. It also appear in my console the reject value `Uncaught (in promise) no name`.

I wonder why my try/catch not working. I also try async/await but the result is the same.

Comment: Maybe `defaultFailCB` throws an exception? What error does it reject with?

Comment: Why are you using a promise here at all? `handleOnAdd` is synchronous.

Comment: *"...but my try/catch does not catch the reject value..."* There is no `try`/`catch` in your code. You're calling `.catch` to hook up a rejection handler, but ...

Comment: You'll also get this if either `exists` or `validNumber` throws.

Comment: .catch handler does nothing unless you are actually handling your rejects in your promise, which you are not. Also why are you using  promise in this case???